# Memory allocation difference between vector::reserve and classical memory allocation

Tags: c++, vector, std, heap-memory

I know that both vector and dynamic memory allocation are using heap.

`char *n = new char[5000000000];`

I can observe increasing allocated memory about 700mb.

```
    vector<char> v;
    v.reserve(5000000000);
```

and in this case, it increased over 4GB.

Is there a difference between the two methods?

Comment: `new` won't initialize allocated buffer (because `char` is primitive type) while `vector` will, this should be a hint...?

Comment: @MikeCAT `reserve` won't initialize anything in the allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*All standard references below refers to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/).*</sub>

---

From [[vector.capacity]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector.capacity#3):

> ```
> void reserve(size_type n);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* A directive that informs a `vector` of a planned change in size, so that it can manage the storage allocation accordingly. After
> `reserve()`, `capacity()` is **greater or equal** to the argument of
> `reserve` if reallocation happens; and equal to the previous value of
> `capacity()` otherwise. Reallocation happens at this point if and only
> if the current capacity is less than the argument of `reserve()`. If
> an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a
> non-`CopyInsertable` type, there are no effects.

A given (compiler) implementation is free to implement its own (typically amortized) growth strategy, and the only guarantee we can use when analyzing a `std::vector` object growth is that the `capacity()` after invocation of `reserve()` will be **greater or equal to** the argument passed for the `reserve()` function. I.e., an implementation is not allowed to allocate **less** than the provided (asked for) argument, even if it can realize, by some clever program analysis, that parts of the allocated storage will never be used.

When allocating memory using a *new-expression*, however, there are a number of special rules, as governed by [[expr.new]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#10) through [[expr.new]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#12), that *allow* implementers a larger freedom in how allocation resulting from a *new-expression* is performed; e.g. from  [[expr.new]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#10) [extract]:

> An implementation is allowed to omit a call to a replaceable global
> allocation function ([new.delete.single], [new.delete.array]). When it
> does so, the storage is instead provided by the implementation or
> provided by extending the allocation of another *new-expression*. The
> implementation may extend the allocation of a *new-expression* `e1` to
> provide storage for a new-expression `e2` if [...]

Depending on the context of your particular program, this could explain why you see a smaller dynamic memory footprint for the result of the `new char[5000000000]` expression as compared to the `v.reserve(5000000000)` invocation.